# How to get css display property value in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following html with css style and js:

```
<p>This is a text
  <br />
  <a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i1', 'i2')">
    <span id="i1" class="show">(show more)</span>
  </a>
</p>
<p id="i2" class="hidden">This is hidden text
  <br />
  <a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i1', 'i2')">(hide me) 
  </a>
</p>
```

and my css:

```
.show {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

In web view: this shows like this as expected.

```
 This is a text
 (show more)
```

and here is the js function:

```
function showHideBlock(id) 
{
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  var display = e.style.display;
  console.log(typeof display)
  console.log(display)
  if (display === 'block') {
    display = 'none';
  } else {
    display = 'block';
  }
  e.style.display = display;
}

function showHideBlocks(id1, id2)
{
  showHideBlock(id1);
  showHideBlock(id2);
}
```

First time, I click on "(show more)", the hidden block is displayed, partially as expected:

```
This is text
(show more)

This is hidden text
(hide me)
```

However, the text "(show more)" is still displayed, expected hidden! This is expected:

```
This is text

This is hidden text
(hide me)
```

Then, I click on "(hide me)", the text "(show more)" and the next paragraph are all hidden. That means the subsequently calls are working (since display are assigned by string 'block' or 'none').

```
This is text
```

I have added log message to the js function. I notice that for the first time, display is string type but value is empty!(the second line should be empty, I use "" to emphasize the empty)

```
string
""
```

How can I get its property as "block" or "none" for the first time?

Thanks @AnhPC03 for correction. But the problem is still the same. I have updated codes in the question. Actually the above codes are simplified from my project.

Comment: `style.display` will only show the value found in the `style` attribute - not the *actual* display value. If you don't specify `style="display:block"` to start with - this code does not work as you are only showing if it is set to `none`. You could change the if statement to `if(display === "block" || display === ""){` as long as you aren't hiding via CSS.

Comment: The example you've shown here is different from your original code. Here you are specifying `style="display:block"` whereas on your original code, you are not.

Comment: @David.Chu.ca Your code is working perfectly fine. Please check the same in jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4ho0mf6r/ .

Comment: @Rylee, true my original codes using css instead of style directly in html. I removed the original link, avoid complicate the question. The issue is that "(show me)" is not set to hidden first the 1st click. 2nd click, "(show me)" and the 2nd para are gone (hidden).

Comment: The code you've posted here works completely fine. Have you tried adjusting that if statement?

Comment: If you're hiding elements with CSS rules - you would probably be best to check the elements `classList`.

Comment: @Shiladitya You are right. In line style case works fine. However, css case is not working. I have updated my question with css case. I also test it in your link at jsddle.net https://jsfiddle.net/9q7d3s1n/2/

Comment: @David.Chu.ca I have added answer to your question with two different solutions. As your requirement is based on class, I have used `classList.add`, `classList.remove` and `classList.toggle`. Look for Solution 2 as its more neat and clear approach. Link: https://jsfiddle.net/308pgw7o/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest toggling a `class`. I've adjust your code to show how you can do this simply.

```js
function showHideBlock(id) 
{
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  
  if (e.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    e.classList.remove("hidden");
  } else {
    e.classList.add("hidden");
  }
}

function showHideBlocks(id1, id2)
{
  showHideBlock(id1);
  showHideBlock(id2);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a text
  <br />
  <a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i1', 'i2')">
    <span id="i1" class="show">(show more)</span>
  </a>
</p>
<p id="i2" class="hidden">This is hidden text
  <br />
  <a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i1', 'i2')">(hide me) 
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: No need for a "show" class here. If you wanted to include that, you would have additional logic for handling that.

Comment: Just different way to get class name to achieve the expected result. Looks good. @Rylee

Comment: it looks that a tag may have a list of classes. One of them is just for hidden, and others for other UI format, right?

Comment: That's totally up to you and how you want each class to effect an element. By having a separate class for hiding it can make things simpler. Just be aware that you may need to use `display: hidden !important` within the rule if there are more specific rules that also change the display.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED
After the author edit his post
Because in the first block, you have `class` instead of `style="display: block;"` in your `span`, so that you need to check if `display` property is presented or not. If not, get property of that class in css file using `getComputedStyle` method.

```
function showHideBlock(id) 
{
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  var display = e.style.display;
  if (display === "") {
    let style = getComputedStyle(e);
    display = style.display;
  }
  if (display === 'block') {
    display = 'none';
  } else {
    display = 'block';
  }
  e.style.display = display;
}

function showHideBlocks(id1, id2)
{
  showHideBlock(id1);
  showHideBlock(id2);
}
```

Comment: I have updated me codes in the question. But the problem is not resolved with the correction. Thanks!

Comment: @David.Chu.ca I add two `"` notations and it works. You could check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0ym4zt5u/)

Comment: you are right. I have updated my question and comments. In the case of css, it is not working. https://jsfiddle.net/9q7d3s1n/2/

Comment: @David.Chu.ca I've updated my answer, check it in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ygahLtj5/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with [Solution 1](https://jsfiddle.net/308pgw7o/)

```js
    function showHideBlock(id) 
    {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      if (e.classList.contains("show")) {
        e.classList.remove("show");
        e.classList.add("hidden");
      } else {
        e.classList.remove("hidden");
        e.classList.add("show");
      }
    }

    function showHideBlocks(id1, id2)
    {
      showHideBlock(id1);
      showHideBlock(id2);
    }
```

```css
    .show {
      display: block;
    }

    .hidden{
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <p>This is a text
    <br />
    <a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i1', 'i2')">
      <span id="i1" class="show">
        (show more)
      </span>
      </a></p>
    <p id="i2" class="hidden">This is hidden text<br />
    <a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i1', 'i2')">(hide me)</a></p>

    <p>
    Another test with inline style.
    </p>

    <p>This is a text
    <br />
    <a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i3', 'i4')">
      <span id="i3" class="show">
        (show more)
      </span>
      </a></p>
    <p id="i4" class="hidden">This is hidden text<br />
    <a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i3', 'i4')">(hide me)</a></p>
```

Here you go with [Solution 2](https://jsfiddle.net/308pgw7o/1/)

```js
function showHideBlock(id) 
{
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("hidden")
}

function showHideBlocks(id1, id2)
{
  showHideBlock(id1);
  showHideBlock(id2);
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a text
<br />
<a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i1', 'i2')">
  <span id="i1">
    (show more)
  </span>
  </a></p>
<p id="i2" class="hidden">This is hidden text<br />
<a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i1', 'i2')">(hide me)</a></p>

<p>
Another test with inline style.
</p>

<p>This is a text
<br />
<a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i3', 'i4')">
  <span id="i3">
    (show more)
  </span>
  </a></p>
<p id="i4" class="hidden">This is hidden text<br />
<a ref="##" onclick="showHideBlocks('i3', 'i4')">(hide me)</a></p>
```

Comment: Looks good for both solutions. One thing about "Another test", it looks as same as "This is a test". Should the 2nd test using style="display: none;"?

Comment: @David.Chu.ca Are you looking for class and inline css based solution in a single method?

Comment: Thank you! That's OK. I think the current version is working.